# Deploying a webapp on two Tomcat servers on different machines with different OS

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I would like deploy my webapp both on Windows Tomcat 7 and Unix Tomcat 7 one after another or at the same time, if possible. Currently, I am able to successfully deploy my webapp
 on Windows Tomcat using tomcat-maven-plugin and calling `mvn tomcat7:redeploy`. But the limitation is that I have to change my pom so that it points to Unix Tomcat if I want to 
 deploy the webapp on Unix which is very painful. Any ideas on how this can be accomplished ? Please guide.

## pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>win-tomcat</server>
        <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

## .m2/settings.xml

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>unix-tomcat</id>
            <username>manager</username>
            <password>manager</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>win-tomcat</id>
            <username>manager</username>
            <password>manager</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with creating two separate [build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) one for each machine and execute build against both profile one after another

Comment: That's what I thought so initially. Although this is something I have never tried, but will check it out. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to resort to profiles but deploy to both in one go you can define two `<execution>`s like so:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>deploy-windows</id>
      <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>win-tomcat</server>
        <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>deploy-unix</id>
      <configuration>
        <url>http://unix:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>unix-tomcat</server>
        <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Great. I will give this a try.

Comment: Did not work! Getting 401 (Unauthorized exceptions) while executing `mvn tomcat7:redeploy' command when I use above solution. I tested deployment to Unix tomcat server just to make sure that the war gets uploaded there just like Windows and it worked without any problems.

Comment: Just for clarification, what you're saying is that if you have just 1 `<configuration>` in the plugin it works for both Win/Unix? However, if you place the exact same configuration in an `<execution>` block as in my sample this fails? Does it fail for both Win/Unix or just for one?

Comment: Yes, just 1 configuration works for both Unix and Windows. But when I added your code snippet and tried to deploy on both the servers by executing mvn tomcat7:redeploy it fails with 401 exception as mentioned above.